# C++ Server crashes sometimes SIGILL

Tags: c++, debugging, crash

My sevrer sometimes crashes when players walk around.
I tried to run it with debugger, and server got error : Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.

It show line 59 in LogicHandler.
It's function run.
Here is that function :

```
void LogicHandler::run()
{
    try
    {
        unsigned short packetID = (packet->getGroup() * 666) + packet->getType();

        switch (packetID)
        {
        case 666:
            handleQuit();
            break;
        case 670:
            handleLogin();
            break;
        case 672:
            handleCreateCharacter();
            break;
        case 673:
            handleDeleteActor();
            break;
        case 675:
            handleSelectCharacter();
            break;
        case 1345:
            handleMove(); <- HERE OCCURS SIGILL
            break;
        case 11332:
            if(!connection.isLogged())
            {
                throw Poco::Exception("Unlogged access.");
            }
            connection.sendPing();
        default:
            if(!connection.isLogged())
            {
                throw Poco::Exception("Unlogged access.");
            }
            connection.sendPing();
            break;
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        connection.shutdownConnection();
    }
    delete this;
}
```

Here is debugger output :

> Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction. In ?? () ()
>
> ## 1  0x0040624d in LogicHandler::run (this=0x3e9be0) at F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\src\handler\LogicHandler.cpp:59
>
> F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\src\handler\LogicHandler.cpp:59:1387:beg:0x40624d
> At F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\src\handler\LogicHandler.cpp:59
>
> ## 1  0x0040624d in LogicHandler::run (this=0x3e9be0) at F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\src\handler\LogicHandler.cpp:59
>
> F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\src\handler\LogicHandler.cpp:59:1387:beg:0x40624d
> Continuing... Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction. In
> ?? () ()
>
> ## 1  0x0040624d in LogicHandler::run (this=0x3e9be0) at F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\src\handler\LogicHandler.cpp:59
>
> F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\src\handler\LogicHandler.cpp:59:1387:beg:0x40624d
> At F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\src\handler\LogicHandler.cpp:59
>
> ## 1  0x0040624d in LogicHandler::run (this=0x3e9be0) at F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\src\handler\LogicHandler.cpp:59
>
> F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\src\handler\LogicHandler.cpp:59:1387:beg:0x40624d
> Continuing... [Inferior 1 (process 29040) exited with code
> 030000000035] Debugger finished with status 0

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your problem is completely elsewhere. If you are using classes with virtual functions, a possibility is that you are not handling memory properly and overwriting your class' [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), therefore calling undefined instructions. Use tools like `valgrind` to sanitize your memory writes.

Answer (score 0):

Sigill indicates you're corrupting memory by overwriting the memory at the address of the function handleMove() with data at some point prior to the call. Look for buffer overruns. So instead of executing handlemove() you're trying to execute data that doesn't make sense as code, hence SIGILL.

Is compiling with electric fence an option in your environment? If not you'll want to step through carefully with a debugger. and break whenever memory at the address of the function handlemove is written.